# Question about a counterexample in definition of an algebra of set

Tags: measure-theory

I have a hard time in generating counterexamples.

**Definition** A collection of sets $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is called an algebra if

(a) $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$,

(b) $A\in\mathcal{F}$ implies $A^c\in\mathcal{F}$, and

(c) $A, B\in\mathcal{F}$ implies $A\cup B\in\mathcal{F}$.

I have a hard time generating an counter example that agree with (b) and (c) but not (a). Any example will help, but the more elementary the better.

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: The empty collection is the only such example.

Comment: $\mathcal F=\emptyset$ is a counterexample. Conditions (b) and (c) are vacuously true.

Comment: In the same line as former comments: condition (a) can be replaced by $\mathcal F\neq\varnothing$.